# My capacitor is not available anywhere, but there are close ones

Tags: capacitor

I have a Harbor Breeze ceiling fan that has a buzz to it.

I've been told a new capacitor will fix this problem.

It is a C61 e185116 5 wire 250 VAC capacitor with a 4.5uF then a 6.5uF and then a 6.5uF rating. I'm assuming they are the rated uF for each speed. I cant find it anywhere on the web.

I can find a 5uF + 6.5uF + 6.5uF capacitor.

Can I use it in my ceiling fan without any issues (FIRE is my biggest concern) if it shortens the motors life a bit that is okay. That is to say not shortened by a week.

Comment: You could always combine two starter caps which collectively have the right values. Get 5-wire versions so you can easily tie the common leads together.

Answer (score 3):

Those capacitors will usually have a tolerance of anywhere from 5% to 20%.  The exact value isn't critical.  The motor may turn a tad faster or slower on a given setting, but it won't do anything disastrous.

The part you gave as an example (5uF + 6.5uF + 6.5uF) shouldn't catch fire or shorten the life of the fan.

- Make sure that you get a part with the same or higher voltage rating.  A low voltage part **will** come undone if used outside its ratings.
- Make sure you buy a quality part. Cheap parts may be just cheap and blow up on you.  They might also be marked for a higher voltage than they can really handle - buyer beware when buying cheap replacement parts.
- Be careful when you install it.  If you do it wrong, **you** could cause a short circuit that will kill your fan when you turn it on.

Comment: Thank you. there are only two brands to choose from. Dinar and HQRP both are from China